# C++ pointer and array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int arr[]={1,2,3};
int* A=arr;
```

I wonder if `arr` is simply an `int` pointer that points to the first element of the array or
if there's any difference between `A` and `arr`.
Also I wonder: while `&arr` is the pointer points to the whole array, what does `&A` point to?
I'll appreciate it if somebody could explain how `&` works for a pointer.

Comment: Two questions here.  `A` and `arr` are not the same.  `&A` points to an `int*`.

Comment: Actually, the `A` variable **points to a single integer**, no more no less.

Comment: Arrays can be confusing, but don't overthink it. `&A` is the address of `A`, and `A` is a pointer-to-int. That's all there is to it. Yes, it points at the first element of an array, but that doesn't affect its type.

Comment: The `arr[]` is an array, e.g. a contiguous container of integers.  Since the capacity was not specified, the capacity will be determined by the compiler from the initialization list.  The symbol `arr` represents the location of the first element in the array, where as `&arr[1]` represents the location of the 2nd element.

Comment: Apart from the difference in `sizeof(A)` vs `sizeof(arr)` you would find very little practical difference between the two.

Comment: A is a pointer to the first element in the array, not the whole array.  And as a consequence A will have lost all information on the size of the array.

Comment: I think I am still a bit confused about the arr part, Can I  summarise it like this: arr is a special pointer whose value is the same with its own address, then why  arr  points to the first element while &arr points to the whole array

Comment: @Beluga -- no, that's not it. `arr` is the name of an array of 3 `int` values. Where it gets confusing is that theme of an array decays into a pointer to its first element in most cases. So in `int *A = arr;` the name `arr` decays into a pointer to its first element, and `A` gets the value of that pointer. If you do, for example, `sizeof(arr)`, the name doesn't decay, and the result is the size of the array. Similarly with `&arr` -- the name doesn't decay, so the type of `&arr` is pointer to array of 3 `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if arr is simply an int pointer

It isn't. `arr` is an array, and not a pointer. `A` is a pointer.

> what does &A point to?

Just like `&arr` points to `arr` (which is an array), so does `&A` point to `A` (which is a pointer).